# MVC3 Problems After changing DB from SDF to MDF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-ce

Error:

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\IncomeAndExpenditure\IncomeAndExpenditure\App_Data\Transactions.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

At the start of today I was happily accessing my MVC3 application's data in a SQL Server Compact Edition 4 `.sdf` data file. I now need to access this data from an Android app, but the Android app cannot connect to a `.sdf` file, it needs a connection to a `.mdf` file.

So I changed the database in the ASP.NET MVC app to a SQL Server Express and a `.mdf` file. So far so good, after much connection string changing the application runs under VS and connects to the new `.mdf` and allows read/write as expected.

Unfortunately now when I try to access the ASP.NET MVC app directly through a browser (I am running everything on localhost incl. VS, SSMS) I get the error as above. I have spent most of the day going back and forth as per many many posts here, MSDN and elsewhere to the point actually where the browser hung and I lost the will to live.

So after advice from the many posts this is I have tried so far in order to connect from both VS 10 and from MSIE 8 browser:

- Placing database `.mdf` & log in SQL Server Express default data folder
- Placing `.mdf` in `|DataDirectory|` (`App_Data`) folder
- Adding new users in SSMS
- Changing user permissions in SSMS
- Altering `User Instance=True / False` in connection string
- Attempting to connect after Attaching and detaching database `.mdf` & log files

My question:

Is there a straight forward guide somewhere that gives details of 'EVERYTHING' that needs to be done/considered when trying to swap a datasource from a SQL Server Compact Edition `.sdf` file to a SQL Server Express `.mdf` file?

I am using: XP, VS10, SQL Server 2008 R2, MSIE 8

Thanks, carl

Comment: Why is a remote client application like an Android app trying to connect directly to the database behind a web site? What are you trying to do? Where are the connection strings for both clients?

Comment: The Android app isn't directly connecting to SQL server. My problem/question is: now that I have changed the datasource within VS from an SDF to mdf I can no longer access the MVC app via any browser. The current VS connection string is:    connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Transactions.mdf; User Instance=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; Integrated Security=True;   ..But only works from within VS